# How to reference JavaScript file from web application root from display template

Tags: javascript, display-template

I have a display template that uses a javascript file which I would like to have located at the root of my site (web application root).

Using `$includeScript` how can i refer to the file at this location. I would like to avoid hardcoding the full url if possible. 
I know `~siteCollection` will look for it relative to the current site collection but I need to look for it relative to the entire website.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be achieve different ways.

- **Quick way is combination of default JavaScript object and SharePoint page variable.**

  `var url = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + _spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl;`
- **SharePint client Context - 1**

  `function GetSiteUrl()
  {
  var ctx = new SP.ClientContext();
  var site = ctx.get_site();
  ctx.load(site);
  ctx.executeQueryAsync(function(s, a){
     alert(site.get_url()
  )});
  }`
- **SharePoint client Context - 2**
  `function initialize()
  {
     var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
     siteCollec = clientContext.get_site();
     clientContext.load(siteCollec);
     clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, getUrl), Function.createDelegate(this, getFailed));
   }
  function getUrl()
  {
     alert(site.get_url());
  }
  function getFailed()
  {
     alert('Failed to retrieve the server relative URL.');
  }`
- **Page Variable**
  `var siteCollectionURL = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl;`